# Minified react error #301 | Infinity-Loop | Re_rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React,{createContext,useState} from 'react';

export const UserContext = createContext();
export const UserProvider = props =>{
    const [ user,setUser ] = useState({
        logged: false,
        User_info: {
        }
    })
    if(localStorage.getItem('data'))
        {
        setUser({logged:true,User_info:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'))})
        console.log(user.User_info)
    }
    return(
        <UserContext.Provider value={[ user,setUser ] }>
            { props.children } 
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

[image: I don't know why but it is running like a loop]

my component is re-rendering in infinite loop and react limits re-rendering and its throwing error
**Can someone help with this??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably change this line to be:

```
-if(localStorage.getItem('data'))
+if(!user.logged && localStorage.getItem('data'))
```

Update:

When you call `setState()` the component is re-rendered. Your original code is running setState() always causing the infinite render:

- first render
- calls setState() so a new re-render will be queued
- renders again, calls setState, queue a re-render
- renders again, calls setState, queue a re-render
- renders again, calls setState, queue a re-render
- ...

Comment: @LaxmanGupta Updated my answer to explain the infinite render